# Why doesn't \b work in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

Currently trying a bunch of code is like this

```
str2 = "Never say Never\b\b\b\b\b"
print(str2)
```

The book says it is printed like this

```
"Never say "
```

But the actual print is like this

```
"Never say Never"
```

Is there any problem with the program?

Answer (score 0):

no i don't think there is any problem with the code. and try not to run it in idle because it gave me output like:

```
>>> str2 = "Never say Never\b\b\b\b\b"
>>> print(str2)
Never say Never
```

instead  run the same code in good editor like pycharm or so and you'll get perfect result like:

```
str2 = "Never Say Never\b\b\b\b\b"
print(str2)
```

with output:
   `Never Say`

Comment: I get the same output as the OP on a Mac OS terminal, using a script not an IDE.

Comment: @cdarke I use Mac OS too, and get the same output ,but i using Spyder

Comment: @Aditya Shrivastava Thanks a lot. I using Spyder,maybe i can change another IDE.

Comment: The backspace is not destructive, it just moves the cursor.  Try:  `str2 = "Never Say Never\b\b\b\b\b      "` - i.e. 5 spaces after the `\b`s.

Comment: If you  think this answer was what you were looking for in the first place then please declare this as the most perfect one so that green tick appears so i can get more points.